# How to generate types from a json schema with IDEA Golang?

Tags: json, go, schema, code-generation

I saw in another topic that *IntelliJ* has an option menu to generate a POJO from a json schema,
but where is the equivalent function in IDEA Golang?

When I click on a `schema.json` file or `.json` file, containing a some schema, I don't see any option able to generate me the Go types that could be defined inside.

In which menu is it?

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/working-with-json.html#intention-actions-json)

Comment: @Eldar I see it in settings, but I cannot run it.

Comment: I succeeded by copy-pasting. Not easy to use. I have four folders having 160 json schemas inside... It won't be efficient enough, but it's a good tool for checking.

Comment: It is the option of the intention. It works when you paste a json asks you if you want to convert it to go struct. There is also a menu under `Code -> Generate > Type From JSON` Imho this one requires more clicks.